# Simple electric motor setup

Tags: dc-motor

I tried to build an electric motor, but the coil does not move when connected to DC batteries.

At the ends of the coil, 1/2 of the enamel is stripped off. I have tried using 24 VDC and 2.5 VDC but to no luck.

I checked my connections with my multimeter and it showed existing resistance. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong that prevents the coil from turning?

[image]

Comment: In the position shown there is no torque on the windings. Rotate 90° so that one side of the coil is very close to the magnet (which is generating a very weak magnetic field) and make sure that the "brushes" are conducting while in that position. 24 V will cause a very high current to flow and probably burn out the wiring.

Comment: It won't selfstart of course. If you flick it, can you see it spinning down a bit slower when powered?

Answer (score 2):

> At the ends of the coil, 1/2 of the enamel is stripped off.

That is not the correct way to make this type of motor. All of the insulation must be stripped on on one end of the coil and half on the other. Once you have corrected that, the motor should work, but you may need to give it a push.

Once you have basic motor function, you can experiment to find the best motor vs. magnet orientation. You may be able to achieve self starting by optimizing the orientation vs. the way the coil tends to stop. There is a half-turn more wire on one side. That will tend to make the coils stop at a one position every time.